# Injection from powerset of the finite bitstrings to $[0,1]$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I want to find a function $\phi : P (\Sigma_{\text{bool}}^{*}) \to [0,1]$.

I know that this can be done by defining

$$
\phi(\{N(w_1), N(w_2), N(w_3), ..., N(w_n)\}) = N(w_1) + \frac{1}{N(w_2) + \frac{1}{...+\frac{1}{N(w_n)}}}
$$

where $N(w_k)$ appends a $1$ to $w_k$ and interprets it as a number, and using the fact that simple continuous fractions are unique.

I also tried to do this using the function

$$
\begin{equation}
\psi(\{w_1, ..., w_n\}) = 0.w_13w_23w_33...3w_n
\end{equation}
$$

that is, mapping each set to the numer whose base-3 decimal representation is the concatentation of all the the words. I think this works, but I am not sure.

I searched on Math Stackexchange but couldn't find this exact question, please acccept my apologies if it is a duplicate.